# How can I avoid business rules violation due to database concurrency?

Tags: database, concurrency

I can't come up with a better way describe my question in the title. Sorry if the title of this question confuse you.

Say I have a web application for managing courses of a school with the following two tables:
[image]

The business rule is that the number of student of a course cannot exceed the max value.
When someone is trying to register a course, we have the following logic:

1. query from database the current number of student and max number of student of that course
2. check if current number of student < max number of stuent
3. insert a new row to student if the validation pass

However, it seems there is a problem when there are concurrent requests.
Say there is a course with MaxNumOfStudent = 20 and there are already 19 students registered.

Then, when there are two people trying to register the course at the same time, the current number of student queried from database will be 19 for both requests. Both of them will therefore successfully register the course, making the number of student in that course (21) greater than max value (20).

The only way I found on google to deal with database concurrency is to add a timestamp or row version, but this cannot handle the above case. How can I deal with this problem?